# Autenticação com segurança entre sistemas distintos

Tags: php, java, segurança

Meu cenário é o seguinte: Um sistema em php autentica o usuário e deve chamar a minha aplicação(Java) informando que usuário é este.
A minha aplicação não autentica este usuário, apenas recebe um identificador dele e carrega as informações que precisa.
A dúvida é: **Como fazer a comunicação entre sistemas com segurança ?** Hoje tenho um Servlet no Java que recebe uma chamada http post informando o id do usuário, porém qualquer um que interceptar essa requisição pode se autenticar.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Acho que você precisa ser mais preciso em sua pergunta. Esses sistemas ficam na mesma rede interna ou convivem em locais separados, sendo a comunicação via internet?

Comment: Desculpem pela falta de detalhes. Os dois sistemas são web, rodam em redes distintas sendo a comunicação via internet somente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conheço duas maneiras de fazer isso:

- usando SSL na comunicação (mais seguro)
- implementando medidas de segurança você mesmo (caso você não saiba
  implementar SSL e quer economizar tempo)

---

### Implementando medidas de segurança você mesmo

Você pode criar um token, que é uma string qualquer seguindo alguma lógica, ambas aplicações devem conhecer essa lógica para criptografar e descriptografar.
Feito isso, aplique o `md5` nela para virar uma string aleatória, essa string será o seu token, que o PHP deve enviar para o Java, e este por sua vez irá descriptografar para ver se foi autenticado com sucesso, assim fica mais difícil de interceptar.

Mesmo assim, se interceptarem esta comunicação, vão precisar descobrir qual a lógica utilizada para poder burlar novas requisições.

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto. Pelo que consegui de informação até o momento a melhor maneira é usando uma criptografia mesmo por exemplo assimétrica.

Comment: Exato, eu usei md5 para criptografar mas existem outros meios, vai da sua preferência e situação :)

Answer (score 0):

## Acesso remoto

Se servidor de origem e destino ficam em **redes diferentes** e o acesso de um ao outro é remoto, via internet, o mais recomendável é usar autenticação via certificado.

No servidor, o certificado deve ser mapeado para um usuário especial que tem os acessos que o sistema remoto precisa.

Desse modo, a conexão é criptografada e a comunicação segura. Além disso você garante que somente o servidor remoto com aquele certificado vai ter o acesso.

## Rede interna

Se os dois sistemas convivem dentro de uma rede interna, Intranet, você pode utilizar regras no proxy ou firewall da empresa para filtrar os acessos permitidos.

Um exemplo seria permitir o acesso à URL desse serviço somente a partir do servidor onde está o sistema PHP.

## Considerações

Em ambos os casos, mencionei técnicas que delegam a autenticação e a privacidade dos dados para soluções de segurança reconhecidas e comuns.

Evite reinventar a roda (que geralmente não funciona direito), por exemplo criando o seu próprio mecanismo de criptografia.

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões e desculpe pela falta de informação. Achei interessante as sugestões @edson sobre criptografia assimetrica. Estou pesquisando mais sobre o assunto. Obrigado.

Comment: @hebertrfreitas Criptografia assimétrica é praticamente sinónimo de usar certificados.